# Implementing Circular correlation using FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft, correlation

For circular convolution I use :

```
def fft_convolution(a, b):
    return np.fft.irfft(np.fft.rfft(a) * np.fft.rfft(b))
```

now i want to implement circular correlation ... after reading different docs i came up with :

```
def fft_correlation(a, b):
    return np.fft.irfft(np.fft.rfft(b) * np.conjugate(np.fft.rfft(a)))
```

first : Is this correct ?

So far from tests seems to work.

second : why did I have to swap  a <--> b ?

Comment: It is correct. You dont have to swap a and b. When you do `np.fft.irfft(np.fft.rfft(b) * np.conjugate(np.fft.rfft(a)))` is as if you are asking "what is the correlation of `a` campared to `b`

Comment: when i swap  a<->b it seem to preserve left-to-right order on chained ccorr, when i decorrelate them, otherwise doesnt